# defining interface for object that I dont know properties keys of?

Tags: typescript

So I have to create type for object that will always look like:

```
{ key1 : ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'], key2 : ['val4', 'val5', 'val6'] }
```

I want to ensure that values will always be an :string[] type but the key value will be changing, how can I approach that?

Is there something like

```
interface IXXX { [whatever] : string[] }
```

Comment: Doesn't TS have an "any" type?

Comment: Cannot see how would that change anything.

I know the type of my values, what I dont know is the name of my properties (keys)

Comment: You can expose an `any -> string[]` interface then?

Comment: This way `interface IXXX{ [key: string]: String[]}`

Comment: thanks Sami, exactly what I was looking for!